# how to register iframe url to google analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I am developing a website that goes into iframe in company A at company B. I'd like to set up Google Analytics on iframe url.

1. Can I set up Google Analytics by setting only me (Company B), not where I use the iframe tag (Company A)?
2. What should I do if I can?

What I've tried now is to put the code below into the head tag.
As I checked, it worked when I accessed our company A url, but it didn't work when I accessed our company B url.

```
        <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=X-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() {
                dataLayer.push(arguments);
            }
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'X-XXXXXXXXXX');
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you double check your IDs?  It should "just work" as you describe.  The outer frame doesn't have information about the inner frame, usually.

Comment: I received an ID for our company (B) url, and I am using that ID. And I wrote the code above on our company (B) head tag.